# Dynamics of matrices over finite field and Similarity of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, dynamical-systems

Consider a set $M$ of all possible square matrices over a finite field $F_p$.  Now consider a map $f_A(x)=A.x$ where $x$ $\in$ $M$ and also the matrix $A$ is a member of $M$. It is needless to mention that the set M forms a vector space over field itself with the module p addition and modulo p scalar multiplication. So the map $f_A$ is linear.

Consider a dynamical system $X_{t+1}=f_A(X_t)$. Suppose there is an orbit of a vector $u$ $\in$ $M$ is $A.u$, $A^2.u$...$A^k.u$.... Let $v=Pu$ where $P$ is another matrix from the set M. So the vector v is generated by a linear operator $P$.

Question is: Is it possible to derive a matrix B which is ''similar'' to the matrix A such that the orbit of the vector $v$ with respect to the map $f_B$ on $M$ is $B.v$, $B^2.v$...$B^k.v...$ ?

Comment: The trajectory of $v$ under $f_B$ is $v,Bv,B^2v,\cdots$ no matter what $B$ is, no? (I will avoid the word "orbit," since that could suggest a matrix is invertible, as per group actions.)

Comment: Yes, not necessary B to be invertible.

Comment: But isn't the trajectory of $v$ under $f_B$ necessarily $v,Bv,B^2v,\cdots$ no matter what? It doesn't make sense to ask to "derive" a $B$ for which it works for a specific $v$($=Pu$), if it works for all $B$ and $v$.

Comment: B needs to be similar to A.

Comment: Do you understand my comment?

Comment: In the question there is no condition linking $B$ to $A$. For every $B$ it holds that the orbit of $V$ is $Bv$, $B^2v$, ...

Comment: B needs to be similar to A. Is it not a condition?

Comment: So by "similar", I don't think you mean the formal definition of "similar", right? (Matrices $M_1$ and $M_2$ are similar if $M_2 = VM_1V^{-1}$ for some $V$.) You mean "the behavior is the same"? Perhaps the orbit has the same size? You won't get a very good answer unless you more clearly define what similar means.

Comment: Yes, I mean formal definition of Similar matrices.

Answer (score 0):

You require $Bv = BPu = Au$ and $B^2 v = B^2 Pu = A^2 u$.  This requires $B^2Pu = BAu = A^2u$.  So $BP$ has all the same eigenvalues as $A$ and also $B^2P$ has all the same eigenvalues as $A^2$.  These together imply $B$ has the same eigenvalues as $A$ and $P$ has only the repeated eigenvalue $1$ (and is orthogonal).  So your $B$ only exists if $P$ is an orthonormal rotation of the coordinates.